# Voltage generation using 4 LEDs in series. Why does the voltage drop if I add a 5th LED in series?

Tags: voltage, led, kirchhoffs-laws

I am making a device that doesn't use any batteries or outlet power.
I need it to momentarily (<1 s) produce 5V DC or more after a bright light is applied to a hole with a 10 mm diameter. Due to the small diameter, 5 VDC solar cells are ruled out (they measure much more than 10 mm and don't produce 5 V if the light is applied only to an area of 10-20 mm). The receiving "sensor" can be placed anywhere from 0 to 10 mm from the hole.
I have already solved the timing issue, with a 555 delay off circuit. Now I need 5.5 V.

I can't use batteries, so photodiodes are ruled out (they produce much less than 1V when they aren't powered, I would need about 15 and then they are too big to be illuminated through the 10mm hole). Solar cells are also ruled out given their inability to produce 5V with a 10mm window.

I decided to use LEDs as a voltage source using the photoelectric effect. With red LEDs, I can get spikes of up to 1.8 V per LED.

**Here comes the question:**
If I wire four red LEDs in series, I can get spikes of 4.8-5.0 VDC.
But if I wire a fifth led, the output voltage when the light goes through the window gets me spikes of only 1.5-1.8 VDC. Why?

All LEDs have been tested and they work fine. Separately, they produce 1.3-1.8 as expected depending on light angle. I have also tried to wire them in parallel and they give roughly 1.5 V as expected. I know the current is very low and it's not what I am asking. **The LEDs are all wired in series**. I know LEDs aren't the most 'efficient' way to do this, but the efficient ways are not usable in my application. **Please stick to the question or refrain from answering if you have no idea**

Why doesn't the 1.5 V of the fifth series LED get added to the previous 4.8 of the other series LEDs?
All LEDs come from the same batch, same specs, same colour, they work, the wiring is OK, I have tried using different LEDs from the same batch and I always get the same result, I can add the voltage up to 4.8 V, then if I add more, the voltage drops.

Any ideas? Also, given the availability of LEDs, light sources and voltmeters, I would be very thankful it you actually test it for yourself rather than writing what you read in ChatGPT or what you just came up with. Test and then reply.

**SOLVED:** User @dandavis suggests it may be a case of the reverse leakage threshold being crossed.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Sounds like the 5th LED is backwards. Regardless, the current an LED can source in photovoltaic mode is very low (even compared to a photodiode which would be better), so while you can generate voltage you probably cannot extract usable power.

Comment: @user1850479 I updated my original post to answer your comments.

Comment: @winny  I updated my original post to answer your comments.

Comment: Q! You say "spikes" . Why not steady DC. Please explain in question. Q2 What are you measuring with? What impedance? IF you get steady DC you can add capacitors per LED. With "spikes" timemconstats and energy may matter. || Solar cells can be cut cdimensionally small to meet your need. You seem more to be saying "With the components I am using I cannot ... " || A low voltage energy harvesting IC or circuiit will transform < 0.5V to eg 5V.

Comment: Blue LEDs should give higher V. White also.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon No. https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4352/9/10/531

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Spikes because unless you are in an inert environment with fixed temperature and components, the amount of light a led receives varies slightly, so the output voltage also varies. Output voltage is being measured with a precision voltmeter. I am not asking people to provide a better way to obtain the 5.5V, I am asking why the circuit is not obeying KVL when I add more than 4 LEDs. And given the quantum implications of the photoelectric effect I doubt the answer is an easy one.

Comment: You can put photodiodes in series to get more photovoltaic voltage gain, but when you use extremely inefficient diodes it will be practically difficult to make this work due to things like leakage across the diodes and the finite input impedance of your meter. You're probably going to have to experiment to see what is happening when you add the last diode. As a first step, why not measure how much current you have to work with from a diode and look up the input impedance of your measuring device in the 5v range.

Comment: @user1850479 Current is not an issue. The device in question is not what I'm asking about, as I already solved that by using a 555 and a pump circuit to increase the voltage to fit my needs. It works.

What I am asking about is the non-addability of LEDs in series working as a voltage generator, which is something you can test yourself easily at home.

Comment: I understand what you are asking, but as I said already current will be a practical limit on your ability to add very weak voltage sources together like this because real components have things like leakage and finite impedance.    It is possible to add voltage together like you want to, just not necessarily as simple as you may assume. You need to troubleshoot and see what is happening in your specific components.

Comment: "LEDs as a voltage source using the photoelectric effect.": The photoelectric effect produces current not voltage.

Comment: KVL always works. If you don't get what is expected, something else has changed.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon in my extensive testing, you'll actually get more juice from red than blue or white LEDs (especially "water clear" reds), and the most from IR. It's not the same as Vf if you're wondering (I had assumed the same), the junction converts all light with wavelengths _below_ the LED's color into current/voltage.

Comment: if your 5th LED is dark, it acts like an LED, pulling down the voltage to ~Vf at a very low current. I have best results from slim rectangular LEDs that can be stacked. You can put some right-angle ones behind the other top-firing ones to get about 1.5 layers worth. You should be able to get 5v with 3 or 4 water clear red LEDs.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, finally someone who has actually tested this. I am not sure what you mean by dark. The fifth LED is the same type and batch as the others (I have tried with about 10 of them, one by one, same result), same color, and it works when wired with the proper resistor, before and after each test.

Comment: @dandavis Also could you provide a link or specific name for those slim rectangular LEDs you have used? I tried SMD leds at first but they weren't giving me as much voltage as 3mm red clear LEDs. Thank you very much

Comment: i mean if the LED cluster is too big/long or whatever for the hole, and the light you're applying doesn't reach the 5th LED, it can sink power from the others. The only other explanation is there's a reverse leakage threshold being crossed.  Search "red flat led" and look for clear ones, I think mine were 2x5x7mm...

Comment: @dandavis Testing was done without the hole, so light was reaching all five leds. I also arranged them in a converging manner so that the focal point, so to say, was the light source. Out of all the things people have said, reverse leakage makes the most sense to me. Thank you for your contribution. If you write all of your comments in a single answer I will tag it as the correct answer.

Comment: interesting. You might try a green led somewhere in the chain as the, see if that affects anything. I would also try the solar cell with a 1cm thick piece of styrofoam or soft plastic packing foam in front to act as a light pipe; once all the individual cells have some light, it will output it rated voltage, open circuit at least. Line the cavity with foil as well, or at least paint it bright white.

Comment: @dandavis Your comments are incredibly helpful. I had already made the device work, and yes I had the cavity in a cone-shaped fashion and with the interior lined in highly reflective material. But I hadn't thought about the styrofoam to make the light even on the receiver, that is very clever. Thank you

Comment: @manubrio  The questions that I asked are relevant to us knowing exactly what you are doing. Exactly what you are doing may or may not be relevant. If we do not know then we cannot tell. Your desire for people to stay on subject is understandable. Equally,if you only cover material that you are sure is releavnt then you may easily miss something vital. FWIW I started playing in tyhis area just over 60 years ago. I have a long lifetime of doing so professionally. It may be that NONE of my questions are relevant. It may not. It would be easier for you to answer the questions than to explain ...

Comment: ... why you do not need to. You may be right. You may be wrong. || Someone else mentioned similar things to what I did. Available LED current, & measuring equipment impedance are quite likely to matter.

Answer (score 0):

User [@dandavis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/146704/dandavis) hits the nail:

> The only other explanation is there's a reverse leakage threshold being crossed.

[Voltage generation using 4 LEDs in series. Why does the voltage drop if I add a 5th LED in series?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689631/voltage-generation-using-4-leds-in-series-why-does-the-voltage-drop-if-i-add-a/689729#comment1837633_689631)

I will also put here some of the useful contributions in case someone reading this is trying something similar:

- Try covering the solar cell with a 1cm thick piece of styrofoam or soft
  plastic packing foam in front to act as a light pipe; once all the
  individual cells have some light, it will output its rated voltage,
  open circuit at least. Line the inside of the cavity with foil as well, or at least
  paint it bright white.
- Red or IR leds produce the highest voltage, because the junction converts all light with wavelengths below the LED's color into current/voltage. It's not the same as Vf.
- I have best results from slim rectangular LEDs that can be stacked. You can put some right-angle ones behind the other top-firing ones to get about 1.5 layers worth. You should be able to get 5v with 3 or 4 water clear red LEDs. Use the flat rectangular ones, about 2x5x7mm (not SMD).
- Use the pump method to increase voltage.
- If you can use batteries, then you can feed the output of the led stack to the base of an NPN transistor through a 100k resistor, and connect the collector to the gate of an SCR that acts as an SMD switch.
- If you can use batteries, use photodiodes, they are much more efficient.

Comment: @dandavis makes valuable contributions and has experimented significantly so the following is NOT a  slight in any way on his efforts. That comment is wrong 9it MAY be the cause),, and basing your understandings on someone's good but only perhaps-correct surmisen greatly risks trapping you in an incorrect assumption set. You have (now repeatedly) ignored other input and pursued an avenue that seems correct to you. Doing so in this case is a minor loss to you. Ifyou do the same in other areas you risk greater losses.